# python 2.7 pandas Dataframe.from_csv Date column not accessible

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Surely I am missing something obvious - but I am baffled by this result:

Environment:

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 
Python 2.7.12
pandas 0.18.1

CSV File:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
12-Aug-16,107.78,108.44,107.78,108.18,18660434
11-Aug-16,108.52,108.93,107.85,107.93,27484506
10-Aug-16,108.71,108.90,107.76,108.00,24008505
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

aapl = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('aapl.csv',index_col=None)

print aapl.columns

print aapl.Low.dtype
print aapl['Low'].dtype

# Fails - KeyError
print aapl['Date'].dtype
```

Output:

```
Index([u'Date', u'Open', u'High', u'Low', u'Close', u'Volume'], dtype='object')
float64
float64
KeyError: 'Date'
```

The mystery to me is that 'Date' appears in the columns list, but I cannot address the column.  What am I missing?

Comment: I bet your file is UTF8 with BOM encoded

Comment: I think you are right.  I'm not sure what the encoding is, but there are definitely special characters buried in there.   print repr(aapl.columns[0])
results in '\xef\xbb\xbfDate'.   Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this out, @Boud answered the question.  Printing the columns with repr(), i.e. print(repr(aapl.columns[0]) showed encoded characters in the key string which prevented it from being found.